# Javascript, execute a function with wide range of delay value?

Tags: javascript

- My JavaScript background app wants to execute a function with user given `delay_value`.
- `delay_value` can be vary from couple seconds to weeks or even months. (can be zero too)

If I just want to delay for couple seconds, I would simply go like:

```
setTimeout (execute_my_function (), delay_value x 1000);
```

How would you suggest me to handle if the `delay_value` is like days or months?

---

**EDIT**. more explanation added. Sorry if my initial question was not explained enough.

- My app runs in a mobile device,
- It consist two parts: 1. UI app which recieves user input, 2. Background service app which I am mentioning in the question
- Background service app communicates to UI app with message port
- User can request to run multiple function at once with respective delay value
- for example,

> run `function A` immediately,
>
> run `function B` after `A` with 5 seconds delay
>
> run `function C` after `B` with 12 hours delay,
>
> run `function D` an hour from now,
>
> then run `function E` on 10th of December

- A user can send multiple request again while timer for many functions are ticking

Comment: what do u mean by `handle `? what do u want to do with `handle `?

Comment: What is a _"JavaScript background app "_: a browser extension, a worker thread on a web page, a server process, an Electron container?

Answer (score 1):

Use `*` operator to convert `day` in `millisecond` :

```
setTimeout (execute_my_function (), delay_in_day * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Use `*` operator to convert `month` in `millisecond` :

```
setTimeout (execute_my_function (), delay_in_month * (365.25 / 12 ) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

or

```
setTimeout (execute_my_function (), delay_in_month * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

For day:

```
newSetTimeout (execute_my_function(), delay_day * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

For month (average 365.25/12 days/month)

```
newSetTimeout (execute_my_function(), delay_month * 365.25 * 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

**FIX**

From @UchihaItachi's answer, max time in setTimeout is 0x7FFFFFFF.
Thus, it would be better to create newSetTimeout as

```
function newSetTimeout(func, time){
    if(time <= 0x7FFFFFFF){
        setTimeout(func, time)
    } else {
        var ctime = Date.now()
        setTimeout(function(){
            newSetTimeout(func, time - (Date.now() - ctime))
        }, 0x7FFFFFFF);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be a bad idea to use setTimeout to delay a function execution for large delay. Also, setTimeout will have a limit of 25 days approx( setTimeout uses a 32 bit int to store the delay so the max value allowed would be 2147483647).

I would suggest to store creation time , delay and check according to what date is now. If the delay is more than the limit then call later

```js
var delayedFns=[];

var timeoutFn=function(creation_time,delay_value,fn){
 var delayNow = (new Date()-creation_time)+(delay_value*1000); 
 if(delayNow <  2147483647){
   setTimeout(fn, delay_value*1000);
 }else{ 
   delayedFns.push({
    fn:fn,
    delay_value:delay_value, 
    creation_time:creation_time
   })
 }
}

setInterval(function(){
 var fnObj= delayedFn.splice(0,1);
 timeoutFn(fnObj.creation_time,fnObj.delay_value,fnObj.fn)
},24*60*60*1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout uses 32 bit int to store the delay , so I don't think  you really can use  it directly if you want to wait for a time  with value greater than 2147483647.It will cause an overflow in most browsers , I reckon . You will have to call it  recursively after a certain time .I am assuming delay value is in seconds :

```
var initialTimeOutDate = new Date((new Date()).getTime() + delay_value*1000)
function doTimeoutForLargeData( initialTimeOutDate , execute_my_function ) {
    var  currentTime = (new Date()).getTime();      
    var difference  = initialTimeOutDate.getTime() - currentTime;
    if (difference  >= 0x7FFFFFFF){
        setTimeout(function() {doTimeoutForLargeData(initialTimeOutDate , execute_my_function )}, 0x7FFFFFFF);
    }else{
        setTimeout(execute_my_function, difference  );
    }
}
```

P.S 0x7FFFFFFF is just the the largest 32 bit int , you should use a smaller number